# set window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight in mobile browsers

Tags: android, ipad, mobile, resize, window

i can get the window.innerWidth or window.innerHeight on mobile platforms
such as android of iphone.

```
 var w = window.innerWidth;
```

but i want to set it back to its old value, i mean when the user zooms by pinch, the innerWidth and innerHeight values are changed. i can get the new values, but i want that
the screen size is back to its old position, but i could never change the size by

```
window.innerWidth = foo;
window.innerWidth = 'foopx';
window.resizeTo(foo,bar);
```

None of them worked in android or in iphone, ipad (safari, mobile chrome) above.
How can i remove the effect of pinch zoom? I do not want to block it or disable, user may zoom but after the zoom action i want to de-zoom to back its original position.
how can resize(change) window.innerWidth, innerHeight values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I present to you, an ugly kludge, but so far the only way i know how to do what you want.

Let's say that in your html you've got

```
<meta id="myViewPort" name="viewport" content="whatever" />
```

Then in a script somewhere you've got this

```
function resetScale()
{
    var viewport = document.getElementById('myViewPort')
    var content = viewPort.content;
    viewport.content = 'what=ever, user-scalable=no';

    window.setTimeout(function()
    {
        viewport.content = content;
    },1);
}
```

Yes, the timeout is required. Without it, the scale is not reset.
Also, the viewport takes a moment before it will notice that user-scalable is no longer urned off. I've had delays as long as 10 seconds before you can start zooming again, and other times where you can start zooming immediately.